# Does Merriam Webster dictionary list word senses based on their historical occurrence?

Tags: dictionary

I have noticed that, unlike other dictionaries, MW seems to list word senses based on the order they have appeared throughout history. Was this just a coincidence, or is this true for MW.

Comment: Well, that totally makes sense to do, so probably that's more than coincidence. Welcome to Linguistics SE!

Comment: Thanks :) Another question. Wouldn't it be more convenient to list senses based on their popularity, or frequency of use?

Comment: @modarwish: it depends; different people have different purposes for using a dictionary. For a learner's dictionary, listing by frequency of use might be more convenient. For a historical/etymological dictionary, listing by order of first use is more convenient for some people.